# Do you know a tool to draw on a map

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm looking for a tool to draw a polygon on map from google map api (I found some) but I would like one which allows you to get all the coordinates of all the points of the polygon. Cause at the moment I can only get  the coordinates of the polygon point by point or in Json for examble
Do you know something like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research I found that which worked for me :
http://codepen.io/jhawes/full/ujdgK/ 
Here is the code of the solution :

```
//var myPolygon;
function initialize() {
  // Map Center
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.5190755, -111.9253654);
  // General Options
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.RoadMap
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
  // Polygon Coordinates
  var triangleCoords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(33.5362475, -111.9267386),
    new google.maps.LatLng(33.5104882, -111.9627875),
    new google.maps.LatLng(33.5004686, -111.9027061)
  ];
  // Styling & Controls
  myPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    draggable: true, // turn off if it gets annoying
    editable: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  myPolygon.setMap(map);
  //google.maps.event.addListener(myPolygon, "dragend", getPolygonCoords);
  google.maps.event.addListener(myPolygon.getPath(), "insert_at", getPolygonCoords);
  //google.maps.event.addListener(myPolygon.getPath(), "remove_at", getPolygonCoords);
  google.maps.event.addListener(myPolygon.getPath(), "set_at", getPolygonCoords);
}

//Display Coordinates below map
function getPolygonCoords() {
  var len = myPolygon.getPath().getLength();
  var htmlStr = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    htmlStr += "new google.maps.LatLng(" + myPolygon.getPath().getAt(i).toUrlValue(5) + "), ";
    //Use this one instead if you want to get rid of the wrap > new google.maps.LatLng(),
    //htmlStr += "" + myPolygon.getPath().getAt(i).toUrlValue(5);
  }
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = htmlStr;
}
function copyToClipboard(text) {
  window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);
}
```

```
<body onload="initialize()">
  <h3>Drag or re-shape for coordinates to display below (<a href="https://github.com/jeremy-hawes/google-maps-coordinates-polygon-tool">Github</a>)</h3>
  <h3><a href="http://codepen.io/jhawes/blog/creating-a-real-estate-polygon-tool">See blog post</a></h3>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  <div class="lngLat"><span class="one">Lat</span><span class="two">,Lng</span></div>
</body>
<button id="clipboard-btn" onclick="copyToClipboard(document.getElementById('info').innerHTML)">Copy to Clipboard</button>
<textarea id="info"></textarea>
```